# Using htaccess to create a beautiful URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, href

I want to shorten this URL: 'http://localhost/school/readmore?id=2' (which has to be in quotes as SO will not allow the posting of localhost URLs).  I already make it like this 'http://localhost/school/readmore-2.html' with this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
IndexIgnore *

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^readmore-([1-9]+).html$ readmore.php?id=$1
```

and here is the modified link

```
<a href="readmore-<?php echo $show_row['id']; ?>.html">Readmore</a>
```

But I want the URL look like this 'http://localhost/school/readmore/2'.
Once I tried but it totally failed; here's the script that didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
IndexIgnore *

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^readmore/([1-9]+).html$ readmore.php?id=$1

<a href="readmore/<?php echo $show_row['id']; ?>.html">Readmore</a>
```

At first I thought it worked but the CSS script did not load because I changed '`-`' into this '`/`' at the link and the script read it as a folder.

Comment: Surely `^readmore/([1-9]+).html$` didn't affect your CSS documents when you're specifying a `.html` suffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your `.`

```
RewriteRule ^readmore/([1-9]+)\.html$ readmore.php?id=$1
```

Comment: hello... i want to ask you something :)... when i direct to readmore page... all of my link change.. example : 'http://localhost/school/galery' changes to 'http://localhost/school/readmore/galery'

Comment: That should not happen. You are only matching and rewriting those ewhich start with readmore and end with .html.

Comment: here is my link code <a href="readmore/<?php echo $show_row['id']; ?>.html">Readmore</a>... did i do something wrong?

Comment: change it to, `/readmore/<?php echo $show_row['id']; ?>.html`

Answer (score 0):

Your Browser thinks it is in a subdirectory, so it references to 'http://localhost/school/readmore/style.css' instead of 'http://localhost/school/style.css'

To fix this you should use an absolute path for your stylesheets and links such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/school/style.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/school/style.css" />
```